# Python: import object semantics

Tags: python, import

It looks like when I import an object (a dictionary, for instance), I'm getting a (deep?) copy of it, taken at the moment of import.

A use case. It obviously is not a good style example; I'm interested in the mechanics.

`run.py`:

```
_ARGS = RestrictedDotDict()
...
def _set_args_click(context_params: dict) -> None:
    global _ARGS

    _ARGS = RestrictedDotDict(copy.deepcopy(context_params))
```

`main.py`:

```
from .run import _set_args_click  # type: ignore
...
def main(**kwargs) -> int:
    _set_args_click(click.get_current_context().params)

    from .run import _ARGS  # type: ignore

    if _ARGS.context and not _ARGS.no_console:
        ...
        return 0
    ...
    return 0
```

This code works. That is, the `_ARGS` list gets initialized, and options are valid for the `if` statement.

This way I'm getting the `_ARGS` list not yet set:

`main.py`:

```
from .run import _set_args_click  # type: ignore
...
def main(**kwargs) -> int:

    from .run import _ARGS  # type: ignore

    _set_args_click(click.get_current_context().params)

    if _ARGS.context and not _ARGS.no_console:
        ...
        return 0
    ...
    return 0
```

This effect means that `_ARGS` is not a reference to the object from `run.py`. Probably, it stands to reason: in a language lacking *private* and *const*, this is a good safety practice.

My trouble: I can't find the place in the docs which tells how and why this happens. Probably, they have their own terminology which I am ignorant of.

Comment: You don't get a deepcopy, you get a reference to the actual object in the module at that time. You later re-assign the variable in the module in `_set_args_click` but this is a different object to the one you have already imported

Comment: Sorry, I just don't get it :) . The different object is a different object, isn't it? The different object is a copy: what else could it be? So when and where this different object gets created?

Comment: `from .run import _ARGS` is equivalent to `from . import run; _ARGS = run._ARGS`, you create a local variable with the same name that points to the object in the module. When you later change the variable in the module that does not affect the local var you created. If you used `from . import run` and `run._ARGS` everywhere you would get the updated var when it changed in the module

Comment: Thanks, now I understand! So the code even is not as ugly and unsafe as it looks like :)

Comment: Well, not quite. So the copying happens at `_ARGS = run._ARGS`? Why? If the right side were a reference to an object in the same module, the left side would be a reference to the same object. Where in the book does it say that the right side from another module changes the semantics of the assignment?

Comment: Not sure what you mean? When that import is run, the local var `_ARGS` is a reference the object that `run._ARGS` is currently pointing to. When `run._set_args_click` is called, `run._ARGS` is changed to point to a different/new object (`_ARGS =  ...` in the function) but the local var `_ARGS` is still referencing the __old__ object

Comment: Ah, yes. The "real" `run._ARGS` now shifts to the initialized object, while local `_ARGS` stays with the old (empty) dict. Correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct